# What are the best practices for unit testing a decently complex conditional in a method?

Tags: unit-testing

I have this method, which is called from a public setter:

```
private void EmitEvents(IGridCell[] oldGridCells)
{
    bool wasAllInOneGridCell = _isAllInOneGridCell;

    _isAllInOneGridCell = GridCells[0] == GridCells[1] &&
                          GridCells[2] == GridCells[3] &&
                          GridCells[0] == GridCells[2];

    // All points were in the same grid cell before, and still are
    if (_isAllInOneGridCell && wasAllInOneGridCell && oldGridCells[0] == GridCells[0])
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        GridCellExited(this, new GridCellChangeEventArgs(oldGridCells[i]));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        GridCellEntered(this, new GridCellChangeEventArgs(GridCells[i]));
    }
}
```

What this code exactly does isn't too important. I already have a test for the 2 events. What I'm wondering is what approach should generally be taken when testing semi-complex conditionals such as the `if` statement in this method.

Since there are 3 boolean comparisons, there are a total of 8 different combinations. Surely I don't want to write 8 unit tests to cover all of those possibilities. But what do I do then? I'd want to check the positive condition and 1 negative condition at least, but isn't part of the job of unit testing creating a sort of "spec" that the class must adhere to?

Let's say the negative case I choose in my unit test is the one where `_isAllInOneGridCell` would equate to false. Then let's say someone is doing some refactoring and accidentally removes the `&& wasAllInOneGridCell` condition from the `if` statement. They have introduced a bug, but since I didn't write a test to cover this exact mundane case, it will not cause a test to fail.

To summarize, on one hand, I view unit testing as a way of defining a contract that the code must follow in order to protect against regressions. Unfortunately, to uphold this I'd have to do insane things like right 8 unit tests for a one line `if` statement. What is the best route here?

Answer (score 1):

If there are 8 possible input-output scenarios (determined by your conditions) then there's not much you can do to go around that; you either test them all or don't. That's one of the things unit testing is about, like you mentioned - to assure contract and protect against regression.

However, if you find it hard to test your class, it might be a sign some refactoring could help. Moving your complex logic to a separate class (method) springs to mind first. You'll still probably need multiple tests for logic, but doing so decouples it from your `EmitEvents` method, which will end up with tests for actual events verification under two conditions only (*logic passed - raise; logic failed - don't*).

It's always a judgement call in those situations. Is your logic complex enough to make it separate being, or is it still part of class it's in? One way or another, if you want to test your contract fully, I'm afraid there's no short ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fair to lump many test cases into one test if that can make it easier.
As long as you don't add a lot of complexity to the test, and introduce risk of having bugs in the test itself :-)

In some cases it makes sense to generate input combinations in loops etc to cover all combinations, instead of hand coding everything...
I agree, it's always a judgment call though to decide what cases are needed.